# text over image css

Tags: html, css

[text comes over this stack image any idea how to do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EinaJ.png)

div has a text of 3-4 lines, an image and pagination on left side bottom. something like this.

Image vertical-aligned :middle,
text vertical-aligned:middle,
small pagination text on the left bottom side of this background stack image

```
 .image { 
    position: relative; 
    width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
  }

 div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 200px; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
  }
```

Comment: Please share your html code

Comment: use **z-index : -1** for image

Comment: would flex be an option ? http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/KaEywJ

Comment: Thanks @GCyrillus :) needed this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it looks like what you needed, You may use flex, padding and margin:

```css
div {
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EinaJ.png) top center;
  width:620px;
  margin:auto;
  padding:40px 40px 30px;
  height:790px;
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
  justify-content:center;
}
img, p, nav {  
  padding:5px;
  margin:0;
  /* see me */
  background:pink
}
img {
  margin:auto auto 0;
}
nav {
  bottom:30px;
  right:45px;
  margin:auto 0 0;  
  border-radius:0 0 0.25em 0.25em ;
  /* see me */
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  text-align:center;
  word-spacing:0.5em;/* better use margin on links, ... */
}
body {
  background:#777;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/150"/> 
  <p>here is</p>
  <p>some line</p>
  <p>of</p>
  <p>text</p>
  <nav>navigation : <a href> link</a> <a href> link</a> <a href> link</a></nav>
</div>
```

A ressource among others that can be usefull: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to change color #000 of div. or it may problem of z-index

```
div {
    color:Black;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 200px; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    z-index:222;

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make a container div with 'position: relative;', then include the image inside this div and also include the text with 'position: absolute;';

for example:

```
#container {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
}

#container img {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#container span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

and your HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="" alt="" />
    <span>Hello World</span>
</div>
```